# Is there any on-going research on this potentially useful invention?

Tags: develop, us5676977

Is there any on-going research on this potentially useful invention? Why has it not been developed to practical use or for experimentation, for further development? patent: us5676977

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read elsewhere, the medicine mentioned in the patent didn't really work, and the patent has been abandoned.

Comment: It would help if you could include a link to an article where you may have read this. Questions like this are [off-topic for the site](/help/on-topic), but it's still [a good general goal](/help/how-to-answer) to include as much verifiable information as possible in your answer.